# Can creatures move through the area of the Hunger of Hadar spell on the Z axis?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

Can creatures move through the area of the *hunger of Hadar* spell on the Z axis?

Say a killer whale is breaking up through ice, flying through the air, then submerging back into the water. If one were to cast *hunger of Hadar* under the whale while it is in the air, can it cross through the spell's area back into the water?

Comment: Is there a reason you think they *can't*? Is there something specific about Hunger of Hadar that's confusing you?

Comment: Please don't edit the question to mark a question complete. Instead you should see an accept mark next to the answers which you can use to mark one (you may wish to wait a bit to see if they are improved). Completing registration should also allow you upvote answers (to show that they are useful).

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 7):

## *Hunger of Hadar* doesn't prevent movement *at all*.

The [*Hunger of Hadar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunger-of-hadar) spell description states (PHB, p. 251):

> The void creates a warp in the fabric of space, and the area is difficult terrain.

**That's the only effect it has in terms of movement.**

[Difficult terrain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DifficultTerrain) doesn't **prevent** movement; it just makes the terrain cost extra movement (PHB, p. 190). *Hunger of Hadar* doesn't prevent movement.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I've added a line to hopefully make it clearer what difficult terrain does. I wonder if we have a question about falling and difficult terrain.

Comment: It doesn't look like we do. I'd maybe like to see a completion of the though, ie. that the whale falling isn't it spending movement so its fall isn't affected by the spell, but it seems good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on what you're asking, to be honest. The description of the [*hunger of Hadar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunger-of-hadar) spell says (PHB, p. 251):

> You open a gateway to the dark between the stars, a region infested with unknown horrors. A 20-foot-radius sphere of blackness and bitter cold appears, centered on a point with range and lasting for the duration. This void is filled with a cacophony of soft whispers and slurping noises that can be heard up to 30 feet away. No light, magical or otherwise, can illuminate the area, and creatures fully within the area are blinded.
>
> The void creates a warp in the fabric of space, and the area is difficult terrain. Any creature that starts its turn in the area takes 2d6 cold damage. Any creature that ends its turn in the area must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 2d6 acid damage as milky, otherwordly tentacles rub against it.

Maybe you're focusing too much on the word "gateway" in the first sentence?

Apart from the "difficult terrain" part of the spell, there is nothing in the description that limits movement, particularly in any one axis.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the description of *[hunger of Hadar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunger-of-hadar)* (emphasis mine)

> You open a gateway to the dark between the stars, a region infested
> with unknown horrors. **A 20-foot-radius sphere** of blackness and bitter
> cold appears, centered on a point with range and lasting for the
> duration. This void is filled with a cacophony of soft whispers and
> slurping noises that can be heard up to 30 feet away. No light,
> magical or otherwise, can illuminate the area, and creatures fully
> within the area are blinded.
>
> The void creates a warp in the fabric of space, and the area is
> **difficult terrain**. Any creature that starts its turn in the area takes
> 2d6 cold damage. Any creature that ends its turn in the area must
> succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take 2d6 acid damage as milky,
> otherworldly tentacles rub against it.

I think you are referring to *the area is difficult terrain* (as supposed by @Purple Monkey): since the spell's area is a *sphere*, in your case if the whale is jumping inside this sphere, i.e. if it less than 20 feet away from the source of the spell [in 3 dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Three_dimensions), then it suffers from the effects.

Given that, maybe your question regards the fact that since it is difficult terrain (then the movement is halved) can the whale fall back in water? For falling distances I refer to these answers:

- [Does the 500 feet falling cap apply per fall, or per turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147706/does-the-500-feet-falling-cap-apply-per-fall-or-per-turn)
- [When a character with no fly speed ends their turn in the air, when should they start falling? [duplicate]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174536/when-a-character-with-no-fly-speed-ends-their-turn-in-the-air-when-should-they/174537#174537)
- [When does a flying creature start and end falling?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59359/when-does-a-flying-creature-start-and-end-falling).